# urls giving 404 in joomshopping joomla

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404, product, joomla3.0

I am trying to use joomshopping extension for Joomla to list products.
I added products on home page.
[image]
But clicking on an individual product(or **Buy** or **Detail**) leads to a 404 page

e.g. Buy has a link`http://dev-joomla.mytest.com/cart/add?category_id=1&product_id=2`
and
Detail has link`http://dev-joomla.mytest.com/product/view/1/2`

In the backend it's like this
[image]

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Following solved the issue

In System -> Global Configuration , set the following options to No
[image]

Comment: that works but what I used to Search Engine Friendly URL